# What's up with `code-request`?

Tags: support, tags

I once notice there was a `code-request` tag for when you wanted someone to write the code for you. I don't see it now. What happened? Is it still acceptable to post code requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Also invalid are `plzsendtehcodez` requests.

As well as the equivalent (but considerably less common) `dear-sir-please-do-my-job-for-me-if-you-have-time-and-it-is-not-too-much-trouble` posts.